# How to export a view in Excel format?

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I am using Drupal 8 and I used the [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module which handles XML and JSON as exporting formats.

Is there any way to export data in Excel format?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the module you are using, try the [PHPExcel](https://www.drupal.org/project/phpexcel) module. Some details about it (from its project page):

> The PHPExcel module allows developers to export/import data to/from real Excel files.
>
> The idea behind this module is to have a single module for handling the export or import of Excel files, instead of multiple modules handling specific cases.
>
> The module provides no functionality as-is (the .module file is as good as empty). The phpexcel.inc file must be included to use the export or import functions in your own module.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another view display that is a download link. It can then be added to your main view using the "Attachment" option.

The download link can then be in either a CSV or Microsoft XLS.